# what's the format for `headers.source` in vercel.json

Tags: vercel

I came across an example on the official Vercel website, and I have a question about the "source" key used in the example. At first glance, it appears to be a regular expression. However, I noticed that the pattern "/:path*" does not resemble a typical regular expression. Can anyone clarify the exact format for the "source" key? I couldn't find any information about it on the official Vercel website.

```json
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/service-worker.js",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "public, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "X-Content-Type-Options",
          "value": "nosniff"
        },
        {
          "key": "X-Frame-Options",
          "value": "DENY"
        },
        {
          "key": "X-XSS-Protection",
          "value": "1; mode=block"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "source": "/:path*",
      "has": [
        {
          "type": "query",
          "key": "authorized"
        }
      ],
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "x-authorized",
          "value": "true"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually uses RegExp in the background, but the string you need provide is not exactly RegExp, it's a string that is converted to RegExp.

It follows the same routing technique to ExpressJS.

If your not familiar with ExpressJS, ExpressJS itself uses the path-to-regexp package to convert its routes to RegExp, so you could check that out.

Since searching for how routing works in vercel.json would not give you any results, search for doing the same thing in ExpressJS instead since ExpressJS is popular. Or you can check out how routing in ExpressJS works here. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: It sounds like you are saying Vercel uses [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp)? How do you know this is the case?

Comment: @jtbandes I think ExpressJS documentation mentions the fact that it uses the path-to-regexp package, and Vercel docs mention vercel.json using the same syntax as Express Routing. That how I came to the conclusion that vercel.json is using the same syntax.

Whether its using the same package to parse the route is something I'm not sure about, but my guess is they are using the same package.